# Unknown IC identification - six pin SMD marked ADZ

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Does anyone have any idea what this chip is?

[image]

Comment: You need to provide a better picture. Is that `A0Z` or `ADZ` or perhaps `AOZ`?

Comment: I fell over your question when I was looking for something else. download here and look at page 32 https://www.sphere.bc.ca/download/smd-codebook.pdf